# Google API connection failed

Tags: android, connection, sign, leaderboard

I have a problem about connection.I used google play developer for a reference.I write all needs code but when I tried to connect I am taking this error "Failed to sign in.Please check your network connection and try again".Do you have an idea what can be the problem ?

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .build();

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}`


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                    requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_failure);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(mHelper==null) return;
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}`
```

`

```
    @Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Attempt to reconnect
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}


private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;





 public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                // signed in. Show the "sign out" button and explanation.
                // ...
                startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),
                        RC_UNUSED);
            } else {
                // not signed in. Show the "sign in" button and explanation.
                // ...
                BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(this, getString(R.string.leaderboards_not_available)).show();

            }
```

}

This my androidManifest file

```
       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: Does your `AndroidManifest` have the network access permission and/or any specific Google Play Services permissions?